# multi frame working (admin,user)

Tags: java, swing

i am making java app for my minor project.i am entering correct data but it not allowing to login.i am confused why the code in not working. 
there are 2 fields in my database(username and pass ).i am entering correct data but it allowing me to login 
`

```
public class login extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton jb1;
    JTextField tf3,tf1,tf2;
    ResultSet rs;
    String s2,s1,s3; 
    String a;
    Connection con;
    login(){

         Container c =getContentPane();
            c.setLayout(null);
            c.setBackground(Color.orange);
            jb1=new JButton("submit");
            jb1.addActionListener(this);
            jb1.setBounds(180,370,100,50);


            JLabel jl1=new JLabel("username");
            jl1.setBounds(10,60,100,50);
            JLabel jl2=new JLabel("password");
            jl2.setBounds(10,110,100,50);
            JLabel jl3=new JLabel("user or emp");
            jl3.setBounds(10,160,100,50);

            tf1= new JTextField();
            tf1.setBounds(110,70,200,40);
            tf2= new JTextField();
            tf2.setBounds(110,120,200,40);
            tf3=new JTextField();tf3.setBounds(110,180,200,40);
            tf1.setText("username");
            tf2.setText("password");
            c.add(tf1);c.add(tf2);c.add(tf3);
            c.add(jl1);c.add(jl2);c.add(jl3);
            c.add(jb1);
}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==jb1){
             s1 = tf1.getText();
             s2 = tf2.getText();
             s3 = tf3.getText();

             try{

                 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "scott",   "hr");
                  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from login ");
                   rs = ps.executeQuery();
                   while(rs.next()) { 
                       String username = rs.getString("username");
                       String pass = rs.getString("pass");
                       if ((s1.equals(username)) && (s2.equals(pass))) { 
                         if (s3.equals("Admin")) {  
                           dispose();
                            home f=new home();
                            f.setSize(500,500);
                            f.setTitle("Bank Management System");
                            f.setVisible(true);


                         } else if (s3.equals("user")) {  
                           dispose();

                         } else {
                           dispose();

                         }
                       } else {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "User name and password do" + " not match!","ALERT!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                         break;
                       }
                   }
             }


                  catch(Exception ex) 
                  {
                      System.out.println( ex);
                  }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        login af =new login();
        af.setSize(500,500);

        af.setTitle("login");
        af.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

`

Comment: Shouldn't you be getting the record with entered user name and then compare passwords?

Comment: `select count(*) from login where username=? and pass=?` then check if you have any results and the count is not `0`